# EEA FP cover letter. Final touch down before submission

Tags: eu-citizens, uk-visa, eu-spouses

Below is the cover letter my husband drafted for the EEA FP. Please, I need advice on what to add or change.

> Datexxx
>
> Dear Entry Clearance Officer
>
> Declaration by the EEA National that the Non EEA National would be travelling together
>
> I, xxxx an EU citizen, with Passport number xxx is the spouse of the Applicant, xxx a non EU citizen with Passport number xxx.
>
> I'm writing in support of her application for EEA family permit. We have been married since 2010 and have three Children together (all EU citizen). I would like my wife, xxxx to accompany me to the United Kingdom on 30th January 2019 to live permanently in the United Kingdom with our children.
>
> I respectfully ask that the family permit to be issued as indicated on DIRECTIVE 2004/38C, for which I am submitting the following supporting documents:
>
> - My passport (EU passport)
> - Copy of my EU National Identity card
> - My wife's Passport (Non EU passport)
> - Copy of my wife's permanent Residency card
> - Passport size photo
> - Printed and Signed Application form
> - Marriage Certificates (Original and translated
> - Children's Birth certificate
> - Few family photos
> - Proof of residence and family status
>
> This is an application under EU law and I understand that it will be processed as soon as possible and on a priority basis. Should you need any further  information, please do not hesitate to contact me on tel: xxx and email: xxx
>
> Yours Faithfully,

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick rewrite.  Some comments:

1. It's not clear to me that your application must include a "Declaration by the EEA National that the Non EEA National would be travelling together."  For example, it is not mentioned under [documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide).  Regardless, I would not include the label "Declaration by the EEA National that the Non EEA National would be travelling together" in the letter itself, so I have left it out here.
2. I would mention your husband's nationality explicitly.  From your [other question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/15044/2440) it is apparent that he is Italian.
3. It isn't necessary to cite the EU directive, nor the implementing legislation, but if you do you should name the directive correctly (2004/38/EC).  Including unnecessary details introduces unnecessary opportunities for error, so I have removed that.
4. The passage invoking the directive's promise of speed ("as soon as possible and on a priority basis") is not necessary and could be read as pushy.  I have omitted it.
5. I've removed a lot of capitalization.  In general, capitalization of nouns that are not proper nouns is not necessary and makes a document harder to read.
6. *You* are applying for the permit, not your husband, so *you* are submitting the documents, not he.
7. The list of documents includes "children's birth certificate"; I presume that should be plural since there should be three of them.  I have changed it accordingly.
8. "Proof of residence and family status": In light of your response to [the earlier version of this bullet point](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/posts/15122/revisions), I have changed it to "certificate...."  Don't forget to include a certified translation into English if the original is not in English, and please don't forget to replace *[name of council]* with the actual name of the council that issued the document.
9. I would omit the mention of living permanently in the UK, because it's not necessary to have that intention.  If you do include it, however, **it must be clear that your husband will live in the UK with you,** so it should say "to live permanently in the United Kingdom with our children *and me."*

> Datexxx
>
> Dear Entry Clearance Officer:
>
> I am an Italian citizen, with passport number xxx, writing in support of my spouse's application for an EEA family permit.  My spouse, xxx, is a Nigerian citizen with passport number xxx.
>
> We have been married since 2010 and have three children together (all are Italian citizens). I would like my wife to accompany me to the United Kingdom on 30th January 2019.
>
> In further support of my wife's application, she is submitting the following documents:
>
> - My passport (Italian)
> - Copy of my Italian national identity card
> - Her passport (Nigerian)
> - Copy of her Italian permanent residency card
> - Passport size photo
> - Printed and signed application form
> - Marriage certificates (original and translated)
> - Children's birth certificates
> - A few family photos
> - Certificate of residence and family status (issued by *[name of council])*
>
> Should you need any further information, please do not hesitate to contact me by telephone on xxx or by e-mail at xxx
>
> Yours Faithfully,

Comment: Very well done. You correctly highlight several subtle psychological issues of word use which might easily derail such applications. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Proof of residence and family status is a single document. Actually it's called ***certificato di residenza e stato di famiglia*** in italiano. Its a document one gets from the council showing the list of the family member with the same address or living in the same place that is been registered with the council. However, I got it only to prove we are living together.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.  To respond to something in an answer, though, it's better to post a comment on the answer.  This causes the person who wrote the answer to be notified.  As it is, I was only alerted to this information because of the comment someone else posted on my answer.  Even if you don't have enough reputation to post comments generally, you should always be able to post comments on your own questions and answers, as well as on answers to questions that you've posted.

Comment: I really appreciate this great work you have done, thank you so much.