# EU citizen (Romanian) with Asian (VN) wife want to live in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu-citizens, eu-spouses, eu-settlement-scheme

I am an Eu citizen (Romanian) and I worked for 3 years as an engineer in the UK. I left a few months ago to go to Asia (Vietnam) to get married.

Now, we are going back to Romania and hope we can return to England together. Do we have a chance? Can she get a visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  She should apply for an [EEA family permit, or, if you are already registered under the settlement scheme, an EU settlement scheme family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).  The possible grounds for refusal are few.  The most likely problem you'll face is the suspicion of a marriage of convenience.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will watch to see which one fit for our case and I will apply as soon as we get the European marriage certificate. It should not be a hard process from what i read. A company asked me for 550 £ to apply in my name. I find that a bit pricey.

Comment: @BufanuLoren the UK will want your *original marriage certificate* from the jurisdiction where the marriage took place, translated into English (or Welsh).  You do not need, and should not submit, any other marriage certificate.  I would not use a company.  I would submit the application myself.  If you doubt your ability to compile the materials effectively, though, or if you lack the time, it makes sense to hire someone to do it for you.  I would certainly shop around, and I agree that £550 seems a bit much.

Comment: @BufanuLoren see [EEA family permit refusal](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14735/2440). The refusal reads in part "you have provided an extract of marriage certificate issued by the Italian authorities however ... you were married in Albania.  Therefore, this is not your original marriage certificate...."